# How to proceed processing items when error is occurring?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Consider the following code:

```
    Collection<String> foos = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "X", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");

    Flowable<Integer> integerFlowable = Flowable.fromIterable(foos).map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).onErrorReturnItem(-1);

    PublishProcessor<Integer> processor = PublishProcessor.create();
    processor.map(i -> 2 * i).subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i), e -> System.out.println("error!"));
    integerFlowable.subscribe(processor);
```

The processing is finished when reaching "X".

How can I instruct RxJava to proceed with rest of the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If trying to replace all "invalid" input with a given value, -1 for example, you can provide a different mapper function.

```
Flowable<Integer> integerFlowable = Flowable.fromIterable(foos)
    .map(s -> {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

You could also remove all "invalid" input prior to creating your Flowable.

```
Collection<String> foos = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "X", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
Collection<String> numbers = foos.stream().filter(s -> {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually an upper method from your call hirarchy should handle the Exception in a helpful manner (not just catching). Normally this means that a useful error message is displayed to the user.

For your usecase maybe it's enough to check is the string is a number:

```java
if (s.matches("-?\\d+")) {
    Integer.parseInt(s)
}
```

This is a basic example and may not cover all your usecases (e.g. leading zeros or stuff like overflows).

Comment: Ok, I guess it makes sense not enabling to proceed with the processing if an exception occurred.